# EditText in ListView as Filter for that List: Focus Issues

Tags: android, listview, filter

In my activity I have a ListView with a customadapter. The first item in that ListView is an EditText.
This EditText has a TextWatcher that causes the list to be filtered.

```
search.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
search.setOnFocusChangeListener(focusListener);

TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if(getContext() instanceof ListActivity) {
            ListAdapter adapter = ((ListActivity)getContext()).getListAdapter();
            if(adapter instanceof TCListObjectAdapter) {
                requestfocus = true;
                ((TCListObjectAdapter) adapter).getFilter().filter(s);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
};

OnFocusChangeListener focusListener = new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus && requestfocus){
            search.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    search.requestFocus();
                    requestfocus = false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
```

The filtering of the list happens as expected. But sometimes after the text is changed, the first row of the listview becomes focussed: in this case the cell of the searchbox but not the EditText. If the user wants to continue filtering the list, he first has to select the EditText again.

I don't want to turn off the option to focus cells in the listview for the visial effect.

Any ways to avoid losing focus of the EditText while filtering?

Comment: Is it necessary to have this EditText within ListView? Could you separate it from ListView and maybe this helped it to keep focus.

Comment: It doesn't necessarly need to be inside the ListView. But it has to go offscreen when the list is scrolled

Comment: Sorry to have waste your time, this was a dumb question since that the listview.addHeaderView(View v) fullfills these needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getListView().addHeaderView(new EditText(this));
```

This fullfills these needs.